# When configure flink checkpoint, should I choose exactly-once or at-least-once?

Tags: apache-flink

When I use flink to log data pipeline, data volume about 100G every day,

the flink checkpoint default config is exactly-once, but I worry about this will affect latency.

exactly-once it is necessary? how about at-least-once?

Answer (score 3):

If the computation you perform downstream is idempotent (ie  duplicates do not change the result of your computation), then at-least-once will be more performant  (as it requires less synchronisation).
For more info see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html#enabling-and-configuring-checkpointing).

Is duplicated delivery a problem for your application? Then you may want to use exactly-once. Else at-least-once will offer better performance.
From experience: we started with exactly-once, but soon switched to at-least-once. You may be able to control duplication within Flink, but it is almost impossible to avoid throughout the system. Thus, we built all of our actions to be (testably) idempotent and turned exactly-once off.

Answer (score 3):

Checkpoints in Flink are implemented via a variant of the Chandy/Lamport asynchronous barrier snapshotting algorithm. [Docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/fault_tolerance.html).

Before Flink 1.11, the only difference between "exactly-once" and "at-least-once" has been that exactly-once required *barrier alignment* on any operator with multiple inputs. In general this tends to increase latency; how much it increases depends on the job.

Flink 1.11 has introduced the option of *unaligned checkpoints*. This alternative implementation of exactly-once helps in some cases, sometimes by a lot. [Docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/checkpoints.html#unaligned-checkpoints).

If you aren't happy with the thought of coping with some duplication during recovery, then you may want to so some benchmarking with your app.